# meaning of 本格的 in this context

Tags: meaning, translation

[image]Suna is paying his friend a visit and after they ate some cake he decided to leave.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried looking it up in a dictionary? Jisho/WWWJDIC gives:

> 本格的{ほんかくてき}
>
> Na-adjective
>
> 1. genuine; real; regular; normal; typical; standard; orthodox

本格的にやる: do something for real, be serious about doing it

本格的に勉強している: have been studying seriously

> じゃあ、オレ本格的に帰るわ

> So I am going back, for real.

Comment: thank you. looked it up on jisho but somehow wasn't able to translate the whole sentence properly

Comment: @torajuro Yeah you are right. I see how this word could be somewhat tricky. Because you can use it in formal writing and the dictionaries give some big English words as its definition. But the tricky thing about it is the word is also used in informal settings, as in your case. So the dictionary definitions don't seem to work very well in these contexts.

Comment: Yes, the situation is somewhat like that of "legit", when you look up "legitimate" it's a big word but what people mean when they say is nothing like that at all.